# Can I call sqlite3_column_bytes multiple times?

Tags: c, sqlite

After evaluating a SQL statement, is it guaranteed that multiple calls to `sqlite3_column_bytes` always return the same value? (There is no other SQLite function call between them.)

Any one familiar with SQLite know about its behavior? I cannot find an answer in the documentation.

Comment: It should. Are you finding it doesn't? Post some code.

Comment: @CoryNelson No, I only wondered if it always does so. (I called it in two functions, the `sqlite3_stmt` variable is global so I don't feel like passing the int value.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will. Looking at the documentation in the sqlite3 source code, it will return the same answer *until* you are using one of these: **sqlite3_reset()**, **sqlite3_step()** or **sqlite3_finalize()**. Since you don't do any call in between, it should be fine. The function on its own doesn't alter any memory or "long lasting" variable.